# Make text labels span multiple ggplot facet grid panes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid, ggrepel

How can `geom_text_repel()` labels be made to span multiple `facet_grid()` panes?  For instance, if there are many long labels that do not fit within the proper dimensions of each grid plot, the label should be positioned as if the `facet_grid()` were a single plot.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:3, 5), 
  y = runif(15), 
  label = paste0("very long label ", 1:15), 
  group = do.call(c, lapply(paste0("group ", 1:5), function(x) rep(x, 3)))
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group)) + 
  geom_text_repel()
```

[image: Example of how to not label across facet grids]

If there is another way to group samples on the x-axis that would mimic a column-wise facet-grid, that's perfectly fine too. In my case, I need to group samples by a grouping variable (correspondingly labeled), and then within each group order them by a continuous variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clip = "off"` from `coord_cartesian`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group)) + 
  geom_text_repel() + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

---

If this is not enough, one other option is to use multilining with `stringr::str_wrap`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(label_wrapped = str_wrap(label, width = 20)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, label = label_wrapped)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group)) + 
  geom_text_repel() + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]

---

data

```r
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:3, 5), 
  y = runif(15), 
  label = paste0("very very very long label ", 1:15),
  group = do.call(c, lapply(paste0("group ", 1:5), function(x) rep(x, 3)))
)
```

Comment: Any way to keep labels from extending to the left of `group 1` and to the right of `group 5` (off the coordinates of the combined plot)?

Comment: Yes, use `stringr::str_wrap`. See edited answer.

Comment: thanks, this works if the facets are wide enough to contain the label if using `str_wrap`.  Unfortunately, for my case the facets are too narrow for that.  I found that because my x-axis positions were a simple ordering of points within each group that could use `position_dodge2()` to achieve what I was after without any use of `facet_grid`.